# Converting an image to byte[] by using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 2.0. While parsing a PDF document, I also want to get first page as image and store it to hbase for using it in search results(I am going to create a search list page like search page of amazon.com).

HBase accepts byte[] variable to store(index) a value. I need to convert the image as byte[], then store it to HBase. I have implemented image render, but how can I convert it to byte[]?

```
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file, "");
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            if (document.isEncrypted()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Trying to decrypt...);
                    document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
                    System.out.println("The file has been decrypted in .");
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new Exception("cannot be decrypted. ", e);
                }
            }
            PDPage firstPage = (PDPage) document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
            pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 300, ImageType.RGB);
               // 0 means first page.

            image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 300, ImageType.RGB);                  
            document.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I write `ImageIOUtil.writeImage(image , fileName+".jpg" ,300);` above right above `document.close();`, program creates a jpg file in project path. I need to put it in a byte[] array instead of creating a file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with [ImageIO.write(Image, String, OutputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) which can write to an arbitrary OutputStream rather than disk. [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) can store the output bytes into an array in memory.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
...
// example image
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(4, 3, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

// to array
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", bos);
byte [] output = bos.toByteArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
```

Comment: What library is ByteOutputStream using? is it  `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.ByteOutputStream;`?

Comment: My bad, should have been java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream which is core Java class, updated answer...

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I have to think about how I can get it from hbase and show it as an image on search list.